# Как сохранить sql запрос в phpmyadmin и потом быстро вызывать его не набирая снова?

Tags: mysql

Как сохранить sql запрос в phpmyadmin и потом быстро вызывать его не набирая снова?

Comment: Скопировать в блокнот.

Comment: создать представление